# How to make Lion’s Mail.app work with Gmail archive feature

Tags: gmail, archiving, apple-mail, osx-lion, gmail-imap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop Mail.app in Lion creating an Archive folder for archiving in Gmail?](https://superuser.com/questions/315171/how-to-stop-mail-app-in-lion-creating-an-archive-folder-for-archiving-in-gmail)

I recently upgraded to Lion. Until then I was using Sparrow for my mailing needs. I’d like to give Lion’s Mail.app a try, but the missing support for Gmail’s archive feature is keeping me from it. Does anyone know a way to force Mail.app to just remove the Inbox label from this email instead of adding a Archive label?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking the folder, going to account info, and then there are options to change the mailbox behaviours based on the folders?

Comment: @Sandeep: there is currently no way to change the behaviour of the *Archive* feature, e.g. *Use this mailbox for…* selection like for Drafts, Trash, Sent, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the email from the Inbox and it will remove the *Inbox* label.

Comment: But this deletes the email. That is not what I want.

Comment: It deletes it from the Inbox (i.e. removes the Inbox label) but is still available in the All Mail folder.

Comment: Using backspace here deletes it. I can use the archive button but that moves it to IMAP/Archive, not what I want.